# Running an angular JS mapping function in my cloud function

Tags: arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my angular JS web app the following function runs perfectly:

```
$firebaseArray(orderedPlayers)
            .$loaded(function(loadedPlayers) {
            var normalizedPlayers = loadedPlayers.reduce(function(acc, next) { acc[next.id] = next; return acc; }, {});
            var selectedPlayers = $scope.selection.map(function(num){
                return normalizedPlayers[num];
            });
            $scope.players = selectedPlayers;
```

I tried transferring he function to my cloud function as follows:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
           var users = userSnapshot.val();
           var selection = users.selection;   
 admin.database().ref("Player").child("playerweek8").once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
      let yourArray = [];
   var orderedPlayers = dataSnapshot.val();
   yourArray.push(orderedPlayers);

 var normalizedPlayers = yourArray.reduce(function(acc, next) { acc[next.id] = next; return acc; }, {});
            var selectedPlayers = selection.map(function(num){
                return normalizedPlayers[num];
            });

            var players = selectedPlayers;
```

However, my cloud function returns the error :"selection.map is not a function"

Is there a way to resolve this so that the cloud function runs as it does in the web app?

Below is the a snippet of how the json for my database looks which should make more sense of the above:

```
{
"players" : [
       {"name" : "Yasin 'YB' Amusan", 
        "Team" : "Industry",
        "price": 8000000, 
        "position": "forward", 
        "image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png", 
        "goals": 0, 
        "assists" : 0, 
        "Y" : 0, 
        "R" : 0},
       {"name" : "Hassan 'Hasi' Akinyera",
        "Team" : "Industry", 
        "price": 5000000, 
        "position": "defender",
        "image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png",
        "goals": 0, 
        "assists" : 0,
        "Y" : 0,
        "R" : 0}],

Users: [{
  "1YrpX2W2xnMPoy4YGpZcOE0xJ5g2" : {
    "email" : "muyiwaawoniyi@hotmail.com",
    "fullname" : "Muyiz",
    "selection" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
    "teamname" : "Donawon",
    "total" : 12,
    "userName" : "muyiwaawoniyi@hotmail.com",
    "week1" : 0,
    "week10" : 0,
    "week11" : 0,
    "week12" : 0,
    "week2" : 0,
    "week3" : 0,
    "week4" : 0,
    "week5" : 0,
    "week6" : 12,
    "week7" : 0,
    "week8" : 0,
    "week9" : 0
  },
  "6K9rQiZQ3jaV38WWtDbNwxhqIwc2" : {
    "email" : "dami.etomi@gmail.com",
    "fullname" : "Dami Etomi",
    "selection" : 0,
    "teamname" : "Bayern Neverlosin'",
    "total" : 0,
    "userName" : "dami.etomi@gmail.com",
    "week1" : 0,
    "week10" : 0,
    "week11" : 0,
    "week12" : 0,
    "week2" : 0,
    "week3" : 0,
    "week4" : 0,
    "week5" : 0,
    "week6" : 0,
    "week7" : 0,
    "week8" : 0,
    "week9" : 0
  }
]
```

Comment: What is `selection` in your code?  It's not shown here.

Comment: @DougStevenson hey. I have edited he question to answer the question

Comment: And what is `users` when you examine its contents?  It sounds like its `selection` property isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @DougStevenson  my understanding of how it works is that `users` is an array and `selection` is a key that each user in the `user` array possesses. I tried to reflect this in the database snapshot at the end of the question

Comment: console.log() is your friend when trying to figure out what's in a variable.  I can only guess what's in there.  You can know for certain.